# Does anyone here knows this variable? No one had ever answer this yet in all sites I've been.

Tags: self-study, median, operations-research

what does "W" represents there in the equation 2? 
no one had ever answer this yet in all sites I've been.

here is the source. 
http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperInformation.aspx?PaperID=65933
[image]

Comment: I read the paper,and this paper is just like a statistical exercise. I guess W is related to Mood's test, but the author did not say anything about it. Also do you know what is "predatory open access publisher"? This Journal is one of it.Read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Research_Publishing

Comment: 1. Do NOT keep making new accounts. 2. Do NOT keep reposting the same question.

Comment: Given that the authors don't get the name of the reference they give for the test right, I don't hold out a lot of hope that they got the details right either.

Comment: but you are ignoring it :( why put it on-hold when it is a genuine question? sorry but still sorry @Glen_b i just badly need it

Comment: The only way you will make any progress here is to improve the question that's on hold at your original account. The question can't be answered from the paper. I would suggest you try reading the Siegel reference (except they seem to get the title wrong; I assume they mean Siegel & Castellan 1988 "Nonparametric Statistics for the Behavioral Sciences") and see if you can edit your question to ask about what is done there.